# Setting struct variables - C

Tags: c, memory, struct

I have some code in the following kind of layout, I believe that the `topExample`/`botExample` aren't being set properly when I call `addTopBotExample`. I think this is due to the top bot variables being on the functions stack and so being cleared when the function ends? I have a feeling that perhaps I need to `malloc` the memory first, but am not sure how I would go about doing this are even if its the right approach.

```
typedef struct Example Example;
struct Example {
   /* normal variables ...*/
   Example *topExample;
   Example *botExample;
};

....

void addTopBotExample(Example **example, int someVariable) {
    Example top = createTopExample(int someVariable); //(createTopExample returns a
                                                      //type Example based on some input)
    Example bot = createBotExample(int someVariable);
    (*example)->topExample = &top;
    (*example)->botExample = &bot;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `createTopExample` isn't allocating memory, this is going to cause problems the moment it's called more than once.  Rewrite `createTopExample` and `createBotExample` to use `malloc` and return an `Example*`.  Something like this:

```
Example* createTopExample(stuff)
{
    Example *example = malloc(sizeof(Example)); 
    // ... stuff you do
    return example;
}
```

Then your `addTopBotExample` would look like this:

```
 void addTopBotExample(Example **example, int someVariable) {
     if ((*example)->topExample)
         free((*example)->topExample)
     if ((*example)->botExample)
         free((*example)->botExample)
     (*example)->topExample = createTopExample(int someVariable);
     (*example)->botExample = createBotExample(int someVariable);
     return;
 }
```

Note that this `addTopBotExample` will `free` the allocated memory before calling `malloc` again but before your program ends, you need to call `free` on any lingering `Example`s that used this `addTopBotExample` function:

```
free(exampleInstanceThatWasPassedIntoAddTopBotExampleAtSomePoint.topExample);
free(exampleInstanceThatWasPassedIntoAddTopBotExampleAtSomePoint.botExample);
```

Comment: Thanks this was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have already everything together. Allocate the `Example` in `createTopExample` or `createTopExample`

```
Example *createTopExample(int someVariable)
{
    Example *x = malloc(sizeof(Example));
    /* initialize x */
    return x;
}
```

and in `addTopBotExample`

```
void addTopBotExample(Example *example, int someVariable) {
    Example *top = createTopExample(int someVariable); //(createTopExample returns a
                                                       //type Example based on some input)
    Example *bot = createBotExample(int someVariable);
    example->topExample = top;
    example->botExample = bot;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ooooo, this is bad. The expression "Example top" in the addTopBotExample() function allocated that object on the stack. It'll be trashed after exiting from the function. (Same for "Example bot" on the following line.) Something like this will work better:

```
void addTopBotExample(Example **example, int someVariable) {
  Example *top = createTopExample(someVariable); // NOTE THE *
  Example *bot = createBotExample(someVariable); // NOTE THE *

  (*example)->topExample = top; // NOT &top !!
  (*example)->botExample = bot; // NOT &bot !!
  return;
}
```

And you'll want to write createTopExample and createBotExample so they return pointers:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // For malloc!
Example *createTopExample(stuff)  // Note *. It's returning a pointer.
{
  Example *example = malloc(sizeof(Example)); // Allocate on the HEAP. Lives after this function call.

  // Fill in the fields of example.
  example->field1 = 25; // Note the "->": you're dereferencing a pointer.
  example->title = "Example title";

  return example;
}
```